# How to iterate over the following code inside a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code where it grabs one of the 6 URLs, strips the filename, creates a filepath, saves image file to disk, sends it off to MongoDB GridFS. The only thing that's changing is image size: 32px, 64px, 128px, 256px, 512px, 1024px. Bruteforce approach is to just copy and paste this code 6 times, and you can only imagine what a mess that would be.

How can I place this code inside for-loop where **32** would change to **64**, **128**, **256**, **512**, **1024** for each loop iteration?

```
var filename32 = image32.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
var filepath32 = path.join(__dirname, filename32);
var writestream32 = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename32 });
var imageStream32 = request(image32).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath32));

imageStream32.on('close', function() {
  fs.createReadStream(filepath32).pipe(writestream32);
  fs.unlink(filepath32);
});
```

#### Update.

Ok so this problem is impossible to solve using iterative approach. More info here: [node.js: while loop callback not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868804/node-js-while-loop-callback-not-working-as-expected). **TLDR**: Because node.js and javascript are single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays? I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly because this solution seems silly...

```
// use this array to store file names(urls).
    var imagesName = new Array("32.png", "128.png", "256.png", "512.png", "1024.png");

for (var i = 0; i < imagesName.length; i++) {
    var filename = imagesName[i].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, filename);
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename });
    var imageStream = request(imagesName[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

    imageStream32.on('close', function() {
      fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(writestream);
      fs.unlink(filepath);
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like arrays is the only way to go for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I'm not sure what actually needs to have the image size appended to it, I just guessed the file name.

```
for(var i=32; i <= 1024; i*=2) {
    var filename = image.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') + i;
    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, filename);
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename });
    var imageStream = request(image).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

    imageStream.on('close', function() {
      fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(writestream);
      fs.unlink(filepath);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the use of "i" there?

Comment: @Maresh image size, e.g. filename32, filename64, filename128...Your approach is more general, while this one fits nicely because each size is multiple of 2.

Comment: I think that you understood his problem in a bad way, he says he has 6 url, so 6 filenames. Use of array is required here, your code will give wrong filenames IMO.

Comment: Using array would probably be more robust, but for a very specific case this would work. Might have to do some string manipulation to put the file extension on the end, but it would be the same idea.

Comment: @bitwiser it says image is undefined. I have image32, image64, image128 which are URLs. I've tried `image+i` and `image[i]` it doesn't evaluate it. Still says image is undefined.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what image32 was. In that case Maresh's answer is probably better and you should put the 6 urls into an array like new Array(image32, image64, etc)

Comment: One second, I think I could remove all 6 URLs and use just 1 because the only difference between them is the very end _32.jpg, _64.jpg, etc...

Comment: That would work. So if you got rid of the end (after the underscore) the filename would be set by saying image.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') + i + '.jpg';

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array if all you're doing is doubling the size each time. It's trivial to calculate powers of two, as @bitwiser's answer shows.

But both of the previous answers have a bug. They use the `filepath` and `writestream` variables in the `imageStream32.on('close')` callback, however, this callback is called asynchronously, *after* the `for` loop finishes executing. So all of these callbacks use the last value that these two variables received the last time through the loop, instead of the correct values from the proper loop iteration.

It's easy to fix this: You simply need to call a function for each loop iteration instead of putting the code directly inside the loop body. The function call creates a closure which preserves those variables individually for each image, so you will write and close the correct file for each image.

Also, you didn't define the `image32` variable that the filenames are generated from. Do you really need the complicated regular expression here; don't you know what the image filenames should be? I'm going to assume the filenames are `'image32'`…`'image1024'`, but you can easily change that of course.

So the code would look like this:

```js
function processImages( basename, minSize, maxSize ) {
    for( var size = minSize;  size <= maxSize;  size *= 2 ) {
        processImage( size );
    }

    function processImage( size ) {
        var filename = basename + size;
        var filepath = path.join( __dirname, filename );
        var writestream =
            gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename });
        var imageStream =
            request(image).pipe( fs.createWriteStream(filepath) );

        imageStream.on( 'close', function() {
          fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(writestream);
          fs.unlink(filepath);
        });
    }
}

processImages( 'image', 32, 1024 );
```